# How to download a file using default_storage class in django

Tags: django

I am using Django default_storage API to save my media files.

I am able to save the file, and open the file for writing. But I am not able to download the file.

I used the code below to save the file:

```py
default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(str(a).encode()))
```

Is there any way to download the file in the same way?

I used the code below to download the file, but it is not either downloading or not throwing any error:

```py
 with default_storage.open(filepath, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline ; filename=' +os.path.basename(filepath)
        return response
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.

```
with default_storage.open(filepath, 'rb') as fh: 
        with open('my_local_file','wb') as wh:
            data = fh.read() # You may want to split this into chunks..
            wh.write(data)
```